# Problema para salvar conteúdo C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou tentando fazer uma réplica do bloco de notas, na parte de salvar o conteúdo em richTextBox1.Text eu estou tendo o problema:

> System.IO.IOException:"O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'caminho do arquivo' porque ele já está sendo usado por outro processo.

```
private void salvarComoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
{
    SaveFileDialog fileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    fileDialog.Filter = "|*.txt";
    fileDialog.ShowDialog();
    fileDialog.OpenFile();
    string path = fileDialog.FileName;
    fileDialog.Dispose();
    richTextBox1.SaveFile(path);
}
```

Comment: Poste o código que você usa para abrir o arquivo de texto

Comment: No caso eu não fiz ainda pra abrir, só queria salvar msm. Depois eu faria o resto

Comment: Mas pra dar este erro você tem que estar com algum _stream_ do arquivo aberto. Certamente tem mais código aí. Não tem como te ajudar sem ver a parte com problema.

Comment: O resto é só Evento vazio.

Comment: Você está abrindo o arquivo `fileDialog.OpenFile();`e não fecha então ele continua aberto. tenta `fileDialog.Close()`; antes do `Dispose()`

Comment: Você esta abrindo o arquivo com `fileDialog.OpenFile();` sem motivo algum nessa função, e não esta fechando ele, por isso o erro. O `fileDialog.Dispose();` não fecha o arquivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão seria você usar a cláusula using.
Exemplo:

```
 private void salvarComoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
 {
    using(SaveFileDialog fileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        fileDialog.Filter = "|*.txt";
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();
        fileDialog.OpenFile();
        string path = fileDialog.FileName;
        fileDialog.Dispose();
        richTextBox1.SaveFile(path);
    }
}
```

Utilizando esta forma, ficará mais fácil tanto a leitura do código e não ficará se preocupando em chamar o método Close ao finalizar o processo.

Como o nosso colega falou, o problema pode ter ocorrido por n motivos, mas vou destacar dois:

1. O próprio arquivo pode estar aberto sem ter chamado o OpenFileDialog, ou seja, aberto arquivo por você mesmo.
2. Talvez você esqueceu de chamar o método Close() no OpenFileDialog.

Então tenta utilizar o using quando você criar um objeto do tipo OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog e outros objetos que necessitem que no final o método Close() seja chamado.

Comment: Valeu, eu refiz tudo e agora tá funcionando certinho